# How to let htaccess to create subdomain automatically for each user dynamically

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want to create the sub domain for each single user dynamically. i have tried many solution but still unable to accomplice this.
can you people provide us the main basic guide for this purpose?

we want this URL: `RewriteRule ^([A-zA-Z0-9]+)$ agt_index.php?username=$1`

this gives us: `www.abc.com/abcuser`

we want to change the URL to this: `abcuser.abc.com`

please provide us in detail help for this.

Comment: Have you already made vhost for each user, to be able using that domain?

Comment: I think php is where you should pick that up. If the subdomain is anything other than www, then it's probably a 'view user' entry.

Comment: @Michael You can set a wildcard, like *.thisismydomain.com, as your server alias

Comment: @Michael we did not made vhost for each user yet. can you clear this please?

Comment: See answer below, but i think you should add 
`<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/username
    ServerName www.example.com
    ServerAlias username.example.com

</VirtualHost>`

Something like that! for each user, buy i'm not sure!

Answer (score 1):

You need to first of all have a vhost set up with wildcard subdomains.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/example.com/
    ServerName www.example.com
    ServerAlias *.example.com

</VirtualHost>
```

After this, it would make more sense to use PHP to parse the subdomain and if it its not www or empty, then regard it as a possible username and work from there.

```
$subdomain = substr($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], 0, strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], 'example.com'));
```